# Set min-height property with pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to set an inline style property of a div using javascript. This seems to work to get the value to an alert window:

```
<!-- /returns 890px for me -->
<script>
  alert(screen.height - 10 +"px");
</script>
```

However, this does not set the style for the div with the ID used:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("page-wrapper").style.min-height = screen.height - 10 +"px";
</script>
```

Neither does this:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("page-wrapper").style.min-height = screen.height - 10 +"px";
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use camelCasing for CSS styles in JS

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("page-wrapper").style.minHeight = screen.height - 10  +"px";
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're close. The property is camel-cased without a hyphen, like:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("page-wrapper").style.minHeight = screen.height - 10 + "px"
</script>
```